# How to add row of data to Jtable from values received from jtextfield and comboboxes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, gui-builder

I have a `JFrame` Form which has `JTextField`s, `JCombobox` etc. and I am able to receive those values to variables and now I want to add the received data to `JTable` in new row when user clicks Add or something like that.

I have created `JTable` using net-beans the problem is what would be the code to add data from those variable to the rows of table. A basic example would be appreciated. I have tried numerous example and have added the code to `ActionListener` of the `JButton` but nothing Happens.
The Examples I tried are. [How to add row in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable) and [How to add rows to JTable with AbstractTableModel method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642755/how-to-add-rows-to-jtable-with-abstracttablemodel-method)

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: During the creation of jtable, you would use a table model. Call the addRow() method of table model to add the new row of data.

Comment: Agreed sir I know that this is related to Netbeans but i want to basic idea how i will add the data to row received. A basic example or already existing example would suffice that fulfills my need

Comment: @user3197695 `but i want to basic idea how i will add the data to row received` - everything is described in official Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables,  `A basic example or already existing example would suffice that fulfills my need` - there are working code examples

Answer (score 27):

> Peeskillet's lame tutorial for working with JTables in Netbeans GUI Builder

- Set the table column headers

  1. Highglight the table in the design view then go to properties pane on the very right. Should be a tab that says "Properties". Make sure to highlight the table and not the scroll pane surrounding it, or the next step wont work
  2. Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button to the right of the property **model**. A dialog should appear.
  3. Set rows to 0, set the number of columns you want, and their names.
- Add a button to the frame somwhere,. This button will be clicked when the user is ready to submit a row

  1. Right-click on the button and select `Events -> Action -> actionPerformed`
  2. You should see code like the following auto-generated

     ```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {}
     ```
- The `jTable1` will have a `DefaultTableModel`. You can add rows to the model with your data

  ```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) {
      String data1 = something1.getSomething();
      String data2 = something2.getSomething();
      String data3 = something3.getSomething();
      String data4 = something4.getSomething();

      Object[] row = { data1, data2, data3, data4 };

      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

      model.addRow(row);

      // clear the entries.
  }
  ```

So for every set of data like from a couple text fields, a combo box, and a check box, you can gather that data each time the button is pressed and add it as a row to the model.

Comment: peeskillet and @eatSleepCode Thank you so much you people saved me. Really thanks alot. I achieved what i wanted.

Comment: I was helped by this post

Comment: Don't be so modest peeskillet, this is a great tutorial!

Answer (score 10):

you can use this code as template please customize it as per your requirement.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add(textField.getText());
list.add(comboBox.getSelectedItem());

model.addRow(list.toArray());

table.setModel(model);
```

here `DefaultTableModel` is used to add rows in `JTable`,
you can get more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Got it buddy have accomplished what i wanted

Answer (score 7):

```
String[] tblHead={"Item Name","Price","Qty","Discount"};
DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel(tblHead,0);
JTable tbl=new JTable(dtm);
String[] item={"A","B","C","D"};
dtm.addRow(item);
```

Here;this is the solution.